# Authentication possible in GMongo?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, grails, groovy

I've been using GMongo for a simple Grails webapp that accesses our Mongo instance.  We recently switched on authentication on Mongo, requiring a username+password to access our DBs.  As best I can tell, there's no way to supply a username+password in GMongo (other than using the GORM mechanism, which doesn't apply in our case).

Is there any way to do so?  Or any other way to access a password-protected Mongo DB in Groovy/Grails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs, I think you can do this when you create your GMongo instance:

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential as MC
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress

...

def credential = MC.createMongoCRCredential( "username", 
                                             "dbname",
                                             "password".toCharArray() )
def mongoClient = new MongoClient( new ServerAddress(server), [ credential ] )
def mongo = new GMongo( mongoClient )
```

Comment: Yes, the GMongo creator very graciously added this in v1.3, at my request. :)

https://github.com/poiati/gmongo/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt

Comment: Nice!  Opensource works :-D  Glad you got a smoother solution :-)